# Magento 2 - Command returned non-zero exit code: when try to change to production mode

Tags: magento2, error, permissions, production-mode

when i run `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` or

```
php -d memory_limit=768M bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

I received the following error, how can i fix it?

```
Config "dev/debug/debug_logging = 0" has been saved.
Starting compilation
Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for detai                                                                                                                   ls.
Disabling maintenance mode
Command returned non-zero exit code:
`/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php -f /home/xxxxxx/public_html/bin/mage                                                                                                                   nto setup:di:compile`


[2019-05-18 06:02:04] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2019-05-18 06:02:09] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []


[2019-05-18 06:02:19] main.ERROR: /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php -f /home/myusername/public_html/bin/magento setup:di:compile 2>&1
Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 62.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 62.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 62.0 MiB
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 64.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 64.0 MiB [] []
```

Comment: Can you please provide us the exception.log file? So that it can help us to fix the issue quickly. Thanks

Comment: hi, there seems to be no new content generated in exception.log. permission issue ?

Comment: Can you please run first php bin/magento setup:di:compile and post what you are getting the error?

Comment: no error when i ran "php bin/magento setup:di:compile".

Comment: So you are getting the error when you run this command php -d memory_limit=768M bin/magento deploy:mode:set production ?
Another question currently are you on developer mode or production mode?

Comment: yes, correct. i'm currently changed to developer mode. I am able torun "php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s" by skipping compilation though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93795/discussion-between-shankar-and-kris-wen).

Comment: What is your Magento version and have you tried switching to production mode with 2GB memory limit

Comment: my magento version is 2.2.6. i will try with  2gb

Answer (score 1):

Here is one alternative you can skip compilation while changing mode

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s

-s stands for --skip-compilation, it will skip compilation.

Comment: hi, skip compilation works, but i want to fix the issue eventually.

Comment: Facing same issue after magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 EE upgrade.